# Excel Conditional Format - counting if a cell is formatted

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2010.

I have a worksheet with 4 columns in it.  I have Conditional Formatting (Highlight if duplicate) on the first 2 columns.  The columns can have either text or numbers in the cells.  The formatting works, as any cell in column A that is duplicated elsewhere, both the first one, as well as any additional ones are highlighted.  Column B is the same way.

```
Col A        Col B
P103         847
P103         849
P103         361
P1043        415
P1051        449
P1051        339
P1051        394
P10513       339
```

In this example, column A entries P103 & P1051 would all be highlighted as duplicate.  In column B, both 339 entries would be highlighted as duplicates.

In a new column to the right, I would like to count if any of the cells in column A or column B have been highlighted as duplicates.

```
Col A        Col B    Col C
P103         847       1
P103         849       1
P103         361       1
P1043        415       0
P1051        449       1
P1051        339       1
P1051        394       1
P10513       339       1
```

I would like to use Column C as a filter to exclude any that have one or the other (or both) cells in Col A & Col B flagged as duplicate.

A couple examples I have seen have said they don't work with conditional formatting.  I have tried a couple functions for conditional formatting, but have not been able to get any of them to work.  Chip Pearson's [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm) is one of them I have tried without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: use countif formula. if you want a Boolean response 1 or 0 then use and if statement like such if(countif(A2:A30000,A2)>1,1,0)

Comment: Could you use `countif()`? Or am I missing something (is there a reason you want to base Col. C off the conditional format)? Countif should be able to tell you if there are duplicates.

Comment: What's your end goal?

Comment: End goal is to determine if contents of cell in either column A or column B was a duplicate, or if both A & B were duplicated.  @ScottCraner -solution would work, I think. But it will take 3 more columns (check Col A, Check Col B, Sum at the end of each row). 0 = no duplicates, 1 = 1 duplicate, 2 = both were duplicated.  I had hoped there was a relatively easy way to do it based on the formatting of the cell.

Comment: use an or statement in the if.  If(or(countif(A2:A30000,A2)>1,countif(B2:B30000,A2)>1),1,0)

Comment: I just realized you wanted another option use this If(and(countif(A2:A30000,A2)>1,countif(B2:B30000,A2)>1),2, If(or(countif(A2:A30000,A2)>1,countif(B2:B30000,A2)>1),1,0))

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a formula use:

```
=(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1)+(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1)
```

If the conditional formatting is based strictly on duplicates in the data as suggested, this formula will return what you are looking for. This will return 0 for no duplicates. 1 if one column has duplicates. 2 if both columns have duplicates.